# Could someone explain me how this simple function works

Tags: function, parameters, closures, dart

From http://www.dartlang.org/language-tour/#functions:

```dart
Function makeAdder(num n) {
  return (num i) => n + i;
}

main() {
  var add2 = makeAdder(2);
  print(add2(3)); // 5
}
```

Could you translate this into english....

what is bothering me is not understanding how it works, and it works..

should it be like this `var add2 = makeAdder;` and then at `print(add2(3));` but then it wont work...

Comment: i guess i cant understand when does i or n gets defined, or how through a same parameter.

Comment: This does not look like JavaScript. EDIT: It seems it's from http://www.dartlang.org/language-tour/ -- editing tags.

Comment: i included tag saying dart....and i believe this functionality is very similar if in not all but at least in javascript...anyways i am really stuck here.

Comment: There was no `dart` tag on the post. Anyway, yes, closures also work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `makeAdder(num n)` creates and returns a new function, defined by lambda expression -- `(num i) => n + i`. The `n` is declared with `madeAdder`, while `i` with the lambda expression.

With this, `makeAdder(2)` essentially returns the new function `(num i) => 2 + i`, which is set as the value of `add2`.

This is then called as `add2(3)`, which evaluates `n + i` as `2 + 3`, resulting in `5`.

---

This is also an example of [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):

```
madeAdder(2)(3); // 5
```

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Sorry. Edited, hopefully, for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Translating this to JavaScript syntax -- hope this helps:

```dart
function makeAdder(n) {
  // Returns a new function (closure) that captures the local variable `n`, as
  // it was passed to this function. So if `n` is 10, this function essentially
  // becomes function(i) { return 10 + i; };.
  return function(i) { return n + i; };
}

function main() {
  // add2 is now a function that adds 2 to its given argument.
  var add2 = makeAdder(2); 
  print(add2(3)); // 5 is passed to add2 -- the result is 2 + 3 = 5.
}
```

Comment: even though it didnt make sense in the beginning now its somewhat...thanks.